# Oracle Apex Data Load Definitions

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working with Apex data loading in order to import CSV files. I create 2 different Definitions (Shared Components) because I need to import CSV files with differente columns. I successfully test&debug both and used correctly in the app.
I have an issue due to a file that is not recognized as csv type by one of the data loading page but, just as a test, if I try to upload with the other, the validation pass.

Comment: What version of APEX are you using?

Comment: Version is Oracle APEX 21.2.0